# Get common element from 2 given lists

Tags: scala, listbuffer

So i have this 2 `collections`:

```
import collection.mutable.ListBuffer

val list1 = ListBuffer[(String, String)]()
list1 += (("Italy", "valid"))
list1 += (("Germany", "not valid"))
list1 += (("USA", "not valid"))
list1 += (("Romania", "valid"))

val list2 = ListBuffer[String]()
list2 += "Germany"
list2 += "USA"
list2 += "Romania"
list2 += "Italy"
list2 += "France"
list2 += "Croatia"
```

I want to get new list that contain common countries with specific `condition` for example `valid` so the result will be new list:

```
Italy, Romania
```

Answer (score 9):

When you need to `filter` and `map` at the same time, use `collect`:

```
list1.collect { case (c, "valid") => c } intersect list2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a for comprehension as follows,

```
for ((a,"valid") <- list1 if list2.contains(a)) yield a
```

This comprehension desugars into a `flatMap` and a lazy filter. We pattern match (extract) those tuples whose second item matches "`valid"` and check whether the *validated* country belongs to the second list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should filter, map and then intersect

```
list1 filter(_._2=="valid") map(_._1) intersect list2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define following method:

```
def intersectWithCond[A, B](xs: Seq[(A, B)], ys: Seq[A])(cond: B => Boolean): Seq[A] = {
  xs.filter(x => cond(x._2)).map(_._1).intersect(ys)
}
```

Usage:

```
intersectWithCond(list1, list2)(_ == "valid") // returns ListBuffer(Italy, Romania)
```